# ASP.NET MVC Core Azure Blob Image Resizer

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-blob-storage, imageresizer

I've got an **ASP.NET core application** that uploads images to **Azure**. I am attempting to resize an image using **Magick.NET** before uploading said image to Azure Blob container. So far, I've managed to save the image to a folder in a local hard drive. Is this the correct way of writing this?

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Product products)
{
    var files = products.UploudThumbnail;

    List<string> image = new List<string>();
    List<string> names = new List<string>();

    if (files != null)
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (file.ContentType == "image/jpeg" || file.ContentType == "image/jpg")
                {
                    if (file.Length < 1 * 1000 * 1000) 
                    {
                        var parsedContentDisposition = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition);

                        var fileName = parsedContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('"');
                        names.Add(fileName);

                        fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "-" + fileName;

                        CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
                        cloudBlockBlob.Properties.ContentType = file.ContentType;
                        await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(file.OpenReadStream());

                        image.Add(cloudBlockBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri);


                        const int size = 20;
                        const int quality = 75;

                        using (var image = new MagickImage(file.OpenReadStream()))
                        {
                            image.Resize(size, size);
                            image.Strip();
                            image.Quality = quality;
                            //how to save it into azure?
                            image.Write(fileName);
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("UploudThumbnail", "Max size not accepted");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("UploudThumbnail", "jpeg & jpg are accepted");
                }

            }
        }
    }

    _context.Add(products);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write the image to a memory stream and upload it using the [`UploadFromStreamAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.uploadfromstreamasync?view=azure-dotnet) method.

Example (pseudo):

```
using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    image.Write(memStream);

    memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(memStream);
}
```

Comment: That really worked! It resized my images successfully, and was able to upload it into azure. I don't fully understand how MemoryStream works but from what I gather, the images are not stored in my hard drive but memory is allocated for the image. Will the image be destroyed right after the upload? Or will it occupy memory indefinitely?

Comment: it will be released since its allocated inside the using. Glad to help you